# Methods for Finding Exact Solution For $e^{2x}+p(2x)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, reference-request, lambert-w

I know there are ways using the Lambert W function, and have had answers to simpler examples, for example
$$e^{2x}+1+2x=0\Rightarrow e^{2x}=-2x-1$$
has the solution
$$x=\frac{-1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)$$
which can be found on Wikipedia and is done through a transformation.  What I can't seem to find is reference to higher degree polynomials.  The equation above involves a linear equation.  What about quadratics, cubics, and higher $n$-th degree polynomials?  I know I can use Newton's method to find great approximations, but what about exact?

Comment: The Lambert W function is actually quite artificial itself, so saying the above is exact is only true if you accept that the function is whatever number satisfies the equation...besides do you need to use it for anything? If not, approximations can be quite fun...I'll show you in a minute.

Comment: @Zach466920 How is the W function "artificial?"

Comment: @Dr.MV "...only true if you accept that the function is whatever number satisfies the equation..." Pure opinion, but its mine :)

Comment: @Zach466920 So, are exponential functions and trigonometric functions also "artificial?"  Just curious as to what constitutes the "artificial" nature of a function that is so well-know and studied.

Comment: @Dr.MV Lambert-W is artificial in the same way the gamma function is. Both extremely useful, both very artificially defined. The other functions you mention are artificial but for a different reason, but that's because $e$ is transcendental, so obviously not many values will be exact. Trigonometric functions are motivated from geometry and have many more exact values and identities. I have problems with things being defined to solve otherwise unsolvable problems. I think all the above fall into that trap, but some more than others...

Comment: The Gamma function can be defined by an integral.  It can also be defined by a power series and otherwise.  And this is true of the natural logarithm (e.g, for the natural logarithm, $\log x =\int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$, $\log x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1-x)^n}{n}$) and its inverse $e^x$, the trigonometric and hyperbolic trigonometric functions and their inverse functions, etc.  We take these for granted, but they are simply more common "special functions" than say, Bessel, Hankel, Gamma, Beta,   W, Riemann Zeta, Polylogarithm, Associated Legendre, Chebyshev, Hermite, Elliptic, and so many more.

Comment: Have you ever heard of generalized Lambert functions ? Lambert function is itself powerful with linear-exponential equation but when you go to higher degree polynomial you need its generalizations like the r-Lambert functions and so on...

Comment: @Dr.MV Here's a question that I think is good for comparison. If I define Crobert R as a function that solves the 6th order polynomial equation for x, do I say its artificial or completely ingenious and invaluable?

Comment: @Zach466920 If one can find a set of identities, special values, a power series expansion, an integral representation, relationships with other special functions, inverse , summation etc. for Crobert R, then you have the making of a new "special function."  Can you do that?  And we're done now, OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$e^{2x}+1+2x=0\Rightarrow e^{2x}=-2x-1$$
$$\Rightarrow 2 \cdot x= -(e^{2x}+1)$$
$$(1) \quad \Rightarrow x= {{-(e^{2x}+1)} \over 2}$$
Using the theory of dynamical systems, we see that the right side of (1) has a derivative less than 1 around the values that I hope solve the above. In other words, there's a fair chance the next part will work.
$$x= {{-(e^{2{{-(e^{2x}+1)} \over 2}}+1)} \over 2}$$
So, I just rewrote (1) in terms of itself. Keep going with this...
$$x{{-(e^{2{{-(e^{2{{-(e^{2..}+1)} \over 2}}+1)} \over 2}}+1)} \over 2}$$

Using $-0.5$ as an estimate, I get an estimate of $-0.639...$

Comment: Sure, that works, but what about $e^{2x}=-1-2x-2x^2$?  This is more what I am looking for, and you really can't get it as you have in (1) in terms of x.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven Sure you could, you'll have to give me a few minutes.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven Ok, you got me on that one :) I get oscillating estimates for everything I've tried so far. In other words, you'd have to guess the sign of both the real and imaginary parts of the solution. I got $-0.53-0.6i$, but I don't put much faith in it. I'll post if I get anything good.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven The solution is to use $$x_{n+1}=-\sqrt{-{{e^{2x_n}+1+2x_n} \over 2}}$$ for iteration. Still a solution in terms of itself, but it also has the property of convergence.